# How can you tell which one is ground, left and right in a headset cord?

Tags: communication, soldering, ground

If a cord in a normal 'gaming' headset has three wires, left, ground and right, how can you tell them apart?

Comment: *If* it's going to a 3.5mm stereo connector: tip is left and next band is right.

Comment: L-R measures twice the resistance of the other two connections.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how you know which wire belongs to which signal, then the best way is to use multimeter and track them to connector. I found [this](http://viziozo.com/wiring/microphone-headset-jack-wiring-diagram) page with respective diagrams.

Comment: Thank you very much, could somehow not find that page but it was exactly what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

- often it will have a neutral colour like white. with L/R insulation as colours.
- but you can put 2 needles thru the insulation and measure the R with a DMM.

  - and hear a faint pop  on one side or both.
  - if both, then you missed the ground in that test.